# Detecting an infinite redirect in rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing

In my Ruby on Rails integration test I have

```
assert_redirected_to buyer_deals_path(buyer)
```

This passes. However, in reality it redirects to that page and then redirects again in an infinite redirect.  Is there anyway to detect this?  Or more simply, to detect that it redirected to that page and stayed there (didn't redirect anywhere else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing this inside an integration test (I'm assuming you are, from the tags), it's actually pretty easy:

```
get "/whatever/caused/the/redirect"
assert_redirected_to buyer_deals_path(buyer)

follow_redirect!
assert_response 200
```

I think `follow_redirect!` is only available in integration tests, though, so if you're trying to do this in a functional test you'll have to find something else.